# Unable to create PNG files using R

Tags: r

when I try to create png files using 
R in linux platfrom, my R window hangs. I try to search google about possible causes, but answer. I install Cairio package for R. Has anybody seen this issue?

This is the session info:

```
> library(Cairo)
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Cairo_1.5-1
> x<-1:100
> png(filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,
+ )
```

at this point, it hangs

Comment: Can you add your `sessionInfo()` and provide a reproducible example of your problem?  Otherwise, its hard to know whats going on.

Comment: FYI, you're not using the `Cairo` device to print.  you're using the base R `png` function.  To use the `Cairo` device, you should call `CairoPNG`

Comment: Thank you Justin so much, that worked but it is still puzzling why png or even capabilities() hanging the R

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you're on a linux install without x11, the base graphics should error... not hang.  I'll second what Ben said in Dirk's comments: There is likely something funky about your install and you should probably resolve before you go much further with R.

Comment: Can you `plot` to the other devices?

Answer (score 2):

Look at `capabilities()` and see if it lists PNG:

```
> capabilities()
    jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets   libxml 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE 
    fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo 
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE 
>
```

That's on my Ubuntu machine using the pre-built binary from Michael's repo (mirrored on CRAN) using the Debian package I maintain.  We make sure that just about everything that *can* be provided is provided -- aqua is Mac-only.

Comment: when I issue capabilities(), it also hangs.

Comment: then something is odd about your setup.  How did you install R?

Comment: I am in a very strict environment. I really had to go back and forth with R, X11 all the required packages. I barely got it working but, I probably caused some issues on the way. Does anybody have a good installation manuall that involves R, Rapache? What packages are needed etc